# C# Issue implementing rounding

Tags: c#, decimal, math.round

New to coding and C#.  I've written a piece of code that I'm running into issues with rounding out to 2 decimals. My code is designed to take todays date and subtract it by a future date. The code itself works; but I wanted it to look cleaner than (Days until completion: 115.11560043243519).  Below is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Newport to Owensboro:");
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var endDate = new DateTime(2022, 10, 30);
double remainingDays = endDate.Subtract(currentDate).TotalDays;
Console.WriteLine("Days until completion: {0}\n", remainingDays);
Math.Round(remainingDays, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Fixed-Point Format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) to format the days within the string, without the call to `Math.Round`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Days until completion: {0:F2}\n", remainingDays);
```

If you did want to use `Math.Round`, you need to take the return value from it and use that in your string.

```
double remainingDays = endDate.Subtract(currentDate).TotalDays;
double remainingDaysRounded = Math.Round(remainingDays, 2);
Console.WriteLine("Days until completion: {0}\n", remainingDaysRounded);
```

However I would suggest you use format specifiers if your purpose is solely to format the value for a string.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction and the information on Fixed-Point Format specifier.